# Alinhamento com string.format e unicode

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

Estou tendo problemas com o alinhamento de *strings* ao usar o `.format()`, por exemplo ao fazer:

```
>>> print '{:>6}'.format('agua'}
  agua

>>> print '{:>6}'.format('água'}
 água
```

Note que o primeiro formato sai da forma esperada, 2 espaços + 4 caracteres = 6. No segundo isso não acontece, ficou 1 espaço + 4 caracteres, pois o tamanho dessa *string* unicode é maior do que visualmente vemos

```
>>> len('agua')
4
>>> len('água')
5
```

Isso está 'quebrando' todo o alinhamento da minha saída, existe alguma forma de corrigir isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Em Python *2.x*, use o prefixo [`u`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) para representar a *string* como [Unicode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#unicode):

```
>>> print '{:>6}'.format('agua')
  agua
>>> print u'{:>6}'.format(u'água')
  água
>>>
```